# External SVG icons are not shown in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I want to use SVG icons on my webpage. Therefore, I have created a SVG file (defs.svg) containing all the icon definitions:

```html
<svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height: 0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="img_test" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
 <path class="path1" d="M860.184 52.761c93.399 0 163.812 67.858 163.812 163.782v364.038c0 83.333-65.224 163.97-163.812 163.97h-277.814c-25.609 0-61.008 14.799-79.019 33.044l-180.619 182.944c-18.018 18.222-36.535 12.602-41.359-12.553l-30.289-157.833c-4.827-25.156-26.314-45.597-48.017-45.597h-39.264c-100.936 0-163.804-73.116-163.804-163.97v-364.042c0-98.634 67.858-163.782 163.804-163.782h696.38z"></path>
</symbol>
...
</defs>
</svg>
```

However, when I use the following HTML code to visualize the icon

```html
<svg style="display:inline-block;width:48px;height:48px;fill:#000;">
  <use xlink:href="http://www.example.com/defs.svg#img_test"></use>
</svg>
```

it is not shown in **Firefox** and **Safari**, **BUT** it is visible in **Chrome**. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

PS: Using the given SVG definitions **inline** works in all aforementioned browser, but this approach is not an option for me as I want the SVG to be cached by the browser.

Comment: This shows external useworking on Firefox. I'm not sure what you've done differently. http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-use-05-b.html

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that my server didn't provide a proper **MIME type** for the svg file resource. After manually setting the MIME type in the response header to "**image/svg+xml**" it works in Firefox and Safari too.